# Vector vs List in VB.NET

Tags: java, vb.net, list, vector

I am working on a project for my company and recently we translated a big [java](/questions/tagged/java) project to [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net). Therefore, a `Vector` was translated as a `list`. However I see that [VB.NET also has a `Vector` type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1). My question is, what is the most appropriate way to keep a `Java vector` in `VB`, as `List` or as `Vector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Class Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

> The Vector class implements a growable array of objects. Like an
>   array, it contains components that can be accessed using an integer
>   index. However, the size of a Vector can grow or shrink as needed to
>   accommodate adding and removing items after the Vector has been
>   created.

It sounds like .NET `List(Of T)`. From MSDN

> Represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by
>   index. Provides methods to search, sort, and manipulate lists.

.NET `Vector` type is different type with different purpose. From MSDN

> Represents a displacement in 2-D space.

Comment: Thanks! I have seen all this information, but has not helped me understand what the best approach is.

Comment: @Marievi, it depends on how you going to use this collection. .NET have a lot different types of collections. `HashSet(Of T)` is for example.